# Get row position in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Is this possible? I want to get a bunch of results in a specific order and then find out the position of a row by its id, for example:

```
1, foo
2, bar
3, foobar
```

I want to get the position of 1 in Alphabetical order, it would return 2

Comment: Is the table InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: MYSQL    ....  Say I had a list of comments for a discussion in a database. I want to find the position of the comment which I specify in that particular discussion. (In the comments database there will be a load of different comments for different discussions)

Comment: See existing answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: I looked at that page but I really don't get SQL so could you please put the relevant MYSQL here for me to use, thanks.

Comment: @Jake Stainer: well, you should try and learn then instead of asking "please give me the codez"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, rank FROM 
    (
    SELECT t.id, t.name,
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM TABLE t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY name ASC
    ) `selection` WHERE id=1
```

Modified from this answer >> [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127)

Comment: IME, this is only consistent on InnoDB tables.

Comment: Its too confusing for me, I don't get it

Comment: @JakeStainer AFAICT, the subquery part joins your table with a variable `@rownum` then increments `@rownum` for each record. I put the whole thing in a subquery so that you can then get the rank by using the "WHERE id=" part.

Comment: I've been playing around with this. It needs tweaking to actually get it to work in MySQL:

Answer (score 3):

Working answer (in MySQL):

If you have the following table "names":

```
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | foo    |
|    2 | bar    |
|    3 | foobar |
+------+--------+
```

And you want to know where "foo" ranks alphabetically, then:

```
SELECT z.rank FROM (
    SELECT t.id, t.name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM names t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY name ASC
) as z WHERE id=1;
```

Will produce:

```
+------+
| rank |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

The changes from @potNpan's solution are the addition of `as z` and the change from `@rownum = @rownum + 1` to `@rownum := @rownum + 1`. Now it works :)

Comment: Say I want to know the position of the id "2" in this table, then I need it to return 2 (because its alphabetical in this case) thanks

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP asked. You're giving the first record in alphabetical order, but the OP wants the rank of the record with ID 1 (i.e. the first record in ID order). Probably he wants a more general solution anyway to get the alphabetical rank of any item.

Comment: Say I had a list of comments for a discussion in a database. I want to find the position of the comment which I specify in that particular discussion. (In the comments database there will be a load of different comments for different discussions)

Comment: Oh I think I see. I'll try to achieve that.

Comment: I'm doing this but am just getting the count and not the position!  SELECT `discusComments`.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM `discusComments`
         WHERE (`discusComments`.`id` <= `discusComments`.`id`) AND (`topicID` = 4)) AS position
FROM `discusComments`      
WHERE `discusComments`.`id` = 68 AND (`topicID` = 4)